# embedded jetty 9 restarting the server in every 3 minutes

Tags: embedded-jetty, application-restart, end-of-life

We are updating our embedded jetty server to latest version 9.4.53.v20231009, but it's restating the server in every 3 minutes.
So we tried with little bit older version 9.4.11.v20180605, which is working perfectly, not restarting the server like the latest one, although it comes with 3 vulnerability, which is preventing us to consider this version.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet

We need help how we can prevent the server restart for latest version 9.4.53.v20231009. Please let me know if anyone faced this issue.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Also, Jetty 9.x is now at End of Life - You should be using Jetty 10, Jetty 11, or Jetty 12 at this point in time.  Your version, 9.4.11 is subject to many vulnerabilities now - https://eclipse.dev/jetty/security_reports.php